# Creating nested dict from dict with nested tuples as keys using comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, tuples, list-comprehension

I got a very useful answer for this problem here earlier this year, but there I could use pandas. Now I have to do it with pure Python.

There is a dict like this:

```
inp = {((0, 0), 0): -99.94360791266038,
       ((0, 0), 1): -1.1111111111107184,
       ((1, 0), 0): -1.111111111107987,
       ((1, 0), 1): -1.1111111111079839,
       ((1, 0), 3): -1.111111111108079}
```

Now I want to convert this in a nested dict like this:

```
out = {(0,0): {0: -99.94360791266038, 1: -1.1111111111107184},
       (1,0): {0: -1.111111111107987,
               1: -1.1111111111079839,
               3: -1.111111111108079}
```

How can I do this with an elegant diction comprehension? I just can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd not do this with a dict comprenhesion. Just use a simple loop:

```
out = {}
for key, value in inp.items():
    k1, k2 = key
    out.setdefault(k1, {})[k2] = value
```

Demo:

```
>>> inp = {((0, 0), 0): -99.94360791266038,
...        ((0, 0), 1): -1.1111111111107184,
...        ((1, 0), 0): -1.111111111107987,
...        ((1, 0), 1): -1.1111111111079839,
...        ((1, 0), 3): -1.111111111108079}
>>> out = {}
>>> for key, value in inp.items():
...     k1, k2 = key
...     out.setdefault(k1, {})[k2] = value
...
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(out)
{(0, 0): {0: -99.94360791266038, 1: -1.1111111111107184},
 (1, 0): {0: -1.111111111107987,
          1: -1.1111111111079839,
          3: -1.111111111108079}}
```

To do the same with a dict comprehension is possible, but you need to then sort the keys and use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the keys on on the first tuple element. The sorting takes O(NlogN) time, and a simple loop like the above beats that easily.

Still, for completeness sake:

```
from itertools import groupby
out = {g: {k[1]: v for k, v in items} 
       for g, items in groupby(sorted(inp.items()), key=lambda kv: kv[0][0])}
```

Comment: You _could_ eliminate a line with `for (k1, k2), value in inp.items():` but I guess that's a little less readable.

Comment: @PM2Ring: yeah, I didn't want to use that because then I'd have to explain how the unpacking works.

Answer (score 1):

Naive solution:

```
my_dict = {
            ((0, 0), 0): -99.94360791266038,
            ((0, 0), 1): -1.1111111111107184,
            ((1, 0), 0): -1.111111111107987,
            ((1, 0), 1): -1.1111111111079839,
            ((1, 0), 3): -1.111111111108079
        }

def get_formatted_dict(my_dict):
    formatted_dict = {}
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        index_1, index_2 = k
        if index_1 not in formatted_dict:
            formatted_dict[index_1] = {}
        formatted_dict[index_1][index_2] = v
    return formatted_dict

print(get_formatted_dict(my_dict))
```

Output:

```
{(1, 0): {0: -1.111111111107987, 1: -1.1111111111079839, 3: -1.111111111108079}, (0, 0): {0: -99.94360791266038, 1: -1.1111111111107184}}
```

Comment: Not that naive at all; it's exactly the same as mine with the only difference that I used the [`dict.setdefault()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to get the same behaviour as your `index_1 not in formatted_dict:` test.

Comment: Yep. Apparently, I saw your answer later.